# Visual Studio Text Coloring After Analyze Code Coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

Visual Studio has turned sections of my code to a brown highlight.  As far as I can tell, this happened after I ran Analyze Code Coverage.  How can I turn the highlighting back off now and return to normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically toggle code coverage highlighting through the code coverage window itself.  If you don't already have it open, use the following menu path to open the window: Test->Windows->Code Coverage Results.  You will see the code coverage window has a small toolbar at the top of it.  To the left is a drop down with one or more code coverage result files.  There are a few icons to the right of it.  The first 3 can be used to export the results, import results, or even merge results.  The next one enables you to turn on or off the code coverage highlighting.  The icon itself kind of looks like a few blocks stacked on top of each other...kind of staggered like a brick wall.  The last icon is used to delete the result file.